# Proper use of type_info in relation to mapping components to a type

Tags: c++, type-safety

I'm trying to `map` a components type to the component value itself in a `map`. The following code all works properly. My main question is this. Is storing the `map` key as `std::type_info*` the best way to accomplish what I'm doing? I'm also not digging the ugly `static_cast<T*>` I'm doing during the usage part.

**Entity.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "IComponent.h"
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(void);
    ~Entity(void);
    void AddComponent(IComponent* component);
    IComponent* GetComponent(const std::type_info* typeInfo);
private:
    std::map<const std::type_info*, IComponent*> components;
};
```

**Entity.cpp**

```
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(void)
{
}

Entity::~Entity(void)
{
    for (auto &mapValue : components)
    {
        delete mapValue.second;
    }
}

void Entity::AddComponent(IComponent* component)
{
    const type_info* info = &typeid(*component);
    components.insert (std::pair<const std::type_info*,IComponent*>(info, component));
}

IComponent* Entity::GetComponent(const std::type_info* typeInfo)
{
    return components.at(typeInfo);
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
IComponent* baseComponent = entity->GetComponent(&typeid(PerkList));
PerkList* perkList = static_cast<PerkList*>(baseComponent);
```

Comment: I had the same thoughts, but it works. I -think- it has to do with how types might be defined during program execution. Such as that the type info for a particular class will always be on the stack. Although I am pulling that train of thought out of the air.

Comment: Never mind, just noticed that [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) return and object with static storage. It will last for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: Did you take a look at [`type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index)? Seems more adequate for what you are doing and can be used with an `unordered_map`. (C++11)

Comment: That's actually new to me. I'll look that up right now.

Comment: @glampert It seems as though `type_index` is exactly what I was looking for and is meant as a clean wrapper for all the `type_info` usage in this case. Thank you!

Comment: Pretty sure that the standard does not guarantee that the result of `typeid()` is going to be unique. As a result this is very non portable code. Try constructing multiple shared libraries see if the results are the same across the different libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### type_info:

Using the `type_info` reference is a viable approach, but it can be made better with  [`type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) in conjunction with an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

#### static_cast:

I don't think there is a way around the cast here. You can make it slightly less verbose by defining a template helper method that wraps the type cast:

```
template<class T>
T * Entity::GetComponent()
{
    return static_cast<T *>(components.at(&typeid(T)));
}

// Usage:
PerkList * perkList = entity->GetComponent<PerkList>();
```

One nice extra of this approach is that you can replace the `static_cast` inside with a `dynamic_cast` during debug/dev builds and check that the types are self-consistent. Then add a preprocessor to use the faster `static_cast` for a "release" build if you need to squeeze every cycle.

#### Pointers:

Returning a raw pointer to `IComponent` is questionable to say the least. A raw pointer conveys no ownership, so it is very easy to leak or delete the objects multiple times when you have raw pointers flying around like this. You should take a look at [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) before further expanding your implementation. Or perhaps return just a reference (`IComponent &`) if the caller of `GetComponent()` should not own the object.

#### Minor details:

- Don't add `void` to the parameter list of functions/methods that take no parameters. This is a C-ish style. C++ does not require that; `()` is just as good. So avoid the unnecessary verbosity.
- Empty destructors/constructors should be omitted or [made defaults](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

Comment: I liked your added portion on the pointers. I know my implementation of them was a bit haphazard. Good advice on returning a reference instead of a raw pointer as you're indeed correct about ownership. The entity 'owns' the pointer and that's it, everything else is just borrowing it for use through GetComponent.

Comment: It's also worth noting: `There is no guarantee that the same std::type_info instance will be referred to by all evaluations of the typeid expression on the same type, although std::type_info::hash_code of those type_info objects would be identical, as would be their std::type_index.` Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid